# Deleting a sysfs entry

Tags: linux-kernel, sysfs

i was trying to learn sysfs and was trying to write a simple sysfs directory. The code is as below

```
static struct kobject *example_kobject;

static int __init mymodule_init (void)
{
    pr_debug("Module initialized successfully \n");
    example_kobject = kobject_create_and_add("kobject_example",
                                             kernel_kobj);
    if(!example_kobject)
            return -ENOMEM;
    return 0;
 }

 static void __exit mymodule_exit (void)
 {
     pr_debug ("Module un initialized successfully \n");
    //  kobject_put(example_kobject); <-- Forgot to delete
 }

 module_init(mymodule_init);
 module_exit(mymodule_exit);
```

As shown in the mymodule_exit, i had by mistake forgot to uncomment the code and then inserted and rmmod the module.

Now when i try to insert the module again, the initialization is failing as the entry is already present.

I know, it does not make sense to allow userspace to remove the entry that the kernel made. But, i was still wondering if there is any other way to remove the particular /sys/kernel/kobject_example entry other than rebooting the box.

Comment: Reboot the box or get a handle to it when your module is trying to load and delete and create it again?

Comment: Oh!! i get the second part, any other way in userspace to do it ?

Comment: @Pradheep: Generally, you cannot fix kernel code problems from the user space. In your case, you cannot remove `kobject` being in user space.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, merely doing `kobject_put()` is not good enough, you must use `kobject_del()` instead. `kobject_put()` does not do complete clean-up. In your case, since `kobject_example` is a file (not dir), mere 'put' will still leave the entry in the parent dir (`kset`).

If you must, there is a away to remove such an entry without reboot, and that is by writing another module to do that. Here is what the module should be doing:

```
/* Find the kobj from the path and parent kset */
kobj = kset_find_obj(kernel_kobj->kset, "kobject_example");
...
/* check kobj is not null etc. */
...
/* Remove the sysfs entry */
kobject_del(kobj);
```

This will delete the sysfs entry. Reboot is easy, but this is nifty when your system does not have an option to go out of service.

Comment: i have to disagree with you , kobject_put decrements the reference count of the kobject and hence when the reference count becomes zero, it deletes the object. I think its a much cleaner solution to delete it dynamically using kobject_put.

Comment: kobject_put is good enough if the kobj is not belonging to kset. kobject_del() will additionally call  kobj_kset_leave(kobj) that will remove it from the kset. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, if you are new to kernel programming and are trying out new things prefer VM, it is much easy and fast. Such approach is taken when a highly available system is messed up.

Comment: @user31986: From the description of `kobject_create_and_add`: "When you are finished with this structure, call kobject_put() and the structure will be dynamically freed when it is no longer being used."

Comment: Are you sure no extra handling is needed in case of `kset`?